# EmberJS loop through array show key and value

Tags: ember.js

Ok so I have a pretty simple array of objects that I retrieved with emberjs, now all I need it to do is have something along the lines of

```
{{#each array}}
{{value}}
{{/each}}
```

and have it so that the array is looped by each item, and each item then is looped by each value and I display all the values of that object, I am not sure how to get it to work.

I have used this helper here https://gist.github.com/strathmeyer/1371586 but it's no use, I have no idea where to start, it just seems like such a simple thing I don't understand why handlebars/ember doesn't support it, also does @key work at all with ember?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Handlebars doesn't support looping over objects.

To loop in an array you simply use

```
{{#each item in collection}}
  {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each collection}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```